# Copiar datos de un libro en funcion del dia de la fecha

Tags: vba

estoy atascado con este asunto. Necesito copiar los datos de un fichero ORIGEN, y que en funcion del día de la celda B2 (campo fecha) pegue en valores en el libro DESTINO en la pestaña correspondiente (cada pestaña es un día en el ejemplo, cada pestaña se nombra como 1, 2, 3, 4...). Cada vez que ejecute la macro debería de copiar y pegar valores en la pestaña destino en función del día del campo fecha...No sé si alguien me puede echar un cable.

---

```
Sub Copia()

Dim wbDestino As Workbook, _
    wsOrigen As Excel.Worksheet, _
    wsDestino As Excel.Worksheet, _
    rngOrigen As Excel.Range, _
    rngDestino As Excel.Range

Set wbDestino = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Destino.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Activate

'aquí debería de coger el día 1 del campo fecha de la celda b2 para meterlo en la pestaña 1 del libro destino
Set wsOrigen = Worksheets("Hoja1")
Set wsDestino = wbDestino.Worksheets("1")
Const celdaOrigen = "A1:AA10000"
Const celdaDestino = "A1:AA1000"

Set rngOrigen = wsOrigen.Range(celdaOrigen)
Set rngDestino = wsDestino.Range(celdaDestino)

rngOrigen.Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy

rngDestino.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbDestino.Save
wbDestino.Close

End Sub
```

El problema que no sé como narices indicarle que de una celda donde tengo una fecha con formato 01/10/2019 coger el dia 1 y que copie la unica pestaña activa del libro origen y la pegue en valores en la pestaña "1" del libro destino

Comment: Hola Jose, podemos echarte un cable con el código que tú tengas, ver los errores que te da y ayudarte a corregirlos, pero lamentablemente si no aportas lo que llevas hecho, poco podemos ayudarte. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/301574/edit) tu pregunta y añade capturas de lo que hay y lo que esperas, además, sobre todo, el código que tengas hecho.

Comment: ¿Sería mucho pedir que subas el archivo de excel a algún lado y que hagas uso de https://www.screentogif.com/ para colocar un gif de cómo es que la data quieres que vaya ?

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar únicamente el día de una celda con fecha utiliza la función day():

Si tienes la fecha en A1 escribe: day(sheets(1).cells(1,1)) y te sacará únicamente el día.

Almacena el dia en una variable, por ejemplo dia_buscado:

```
Dim dia_buscado as string

dia_buscado = day(sheets(1).cells(1,1))
```

Sheets(1) es la Hoja1 de tu libro, cámbialo como necesites.

Luego solo tienes que recorrer las hojas de tu fichero origen, buscar la que se llame como el día y copiarla al fichero destino:

```
Sub Copia()

Dim wbDestino As Workbook
Dim wsOrigen As Worksheet
Dim wsDestino As Worksheet
Dim rngOrigen As Range
Dim rngDestino As Range
Dim dia_buscado As String
Dim wbOrigen As Workbook

Set wbOrigen = ThisWorkbook
Set wbDestino = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Destino.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Activate


dia_buscado = Day(plantilla.Cells(2, 1))


For Each ws In wbOrigen.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = dia_buscado Then

         ws.Copy wbDestino

    End If

Next ws

rngDestino.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbDestino.Save
wbDestino.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias, unicamente que no entiendo la parte que indicas wsOrigen, sería el nombre del fichero o de la variable que hemos creado.  Así no me funciona:

```
 Sub Copia()

Dim wbDestino As Workbook, _
    wsOrigen As Excel.Worksheet, _
    wsDestino As Excel.Worksheet, _
    rngOrigen As Excel.Range, _
    rngDestino As Excel.Range
    dia_buscado As String


Set wbDestino = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Destino.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Activate

dia_buscado = Day(plantilla.Cells(2, 1))

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = dia_buscado Then

         wsOrigen(dia_buscado) copy wbDestino

    End If

Next ws

rngDestino.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbDestino.Save
wbDestino.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Te había puesto mal el nombre de la hoja. Edito mi respuesta con el código bueno.

Answer (score 0):

Dowall, me da error en la fila For Each ws In wbOrigen.Worksheets

```
    Sub Copia()

Dim wbDestino As Workbook
Dim wsOrigen As Worksheet
Dim wsDestino As Worksheet
Dim rngOrigen As Range
Dim rngDestino As Range
Dim dia_buscado As String
Dim wbOrigen As Workbook

Set wbDestino = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Destino.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Activate


dia_buscado = Day(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2))


For Each ws In wbOrigen.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = dia_buscado Then

         ws.Copy wbDestino

    End If

Next ws

rngDestino.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbDestino.Save
wbDestino.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Cierto, hay que declarar primero el libro wbOrigen. Escribe esto antes de la linea Set wbDestino....

Set wbOrigen = ThisWorkbook

Edito de todas formas mi respuesta inicial y lo añado. De todas formas la linea rngDestino.PasteSpecial tira un error porque no has declarado antes esa variable.

Comment: ok muchas gracias!! me funciono con tu modificación pero en paralelo conseguir hacerlo de otra forma !! mil gracias

Comment: Marca la respuesta como correcta por favor. Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de Depurar Tu Código de Esta Manera Para Así Ver de Donde Proviene el Error en Tu Código...

```html
Sub Copia()
On Error Resume Next  
Dim wbDestino As Workbook
Dim wsOrigen As Worksheet
Dim wsDestino As Worksheet
Dim rngOrigen As Range
Dim rngDestino As Range
Dim dia_buscado As String
Dim wbOrigen As Workbook


Set wbDestino = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Destino.xlsx")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)

Err.Clear
ThisWorkbook.Activate
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)

Err.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)

If dia_buscado = cstr(plantilla.Cells(2, 1)) Then
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       Err.Clear
       If ws.Name = dia_buscado Then
            wsOrigen(dia_buscado) copy wbDestino
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)   
       End If
   Next ws
   Err.Clear
   rngDestino.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)
   Err.Clear
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)
   Err.Clear
   wbDestino.Save
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)
End If

Err.Clear
wbDestino.Close
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox(Err.Description, 0,Err.Number)
End Sub
```

Comment: Tampoco funciona, me indica error de sintaxis... en :::

            wsOrigen(dia_buscado) copy wbDestino